# JQuery redirect with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I make a mobile version of my website, I have two page "page1.html" and "page2.html" I made a redirection

```
window.location.href = "/page2.html";
```

I want to do an animation , page 2 appears from the top of the page slowly , can i make that ?

Comment: Sounds like making an AJAX request for page2.html loaded into a div offscreen, then animate it dropping in. If you navigate away using `window.location` you won't get that.

Comment: I have similar on my website - http://andrewdunai.com, try navigating thgough menu there. It uses my SlideJS plugin: https://bitbucket.org/AndrewDunai/slidejs/wiki/Home, you may try to examine it and write similar one.

Comment: You can redirect to the URL and show the page on document.ready with an animation

Comment: You can also look into the [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). This way you can load the page via AJAX, make all the animations, and when the animation is over change the browser URL.

Comment: If you're going down this road, I would suggest investigating a framework for [Single Page Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the url in address bar either start using jQuery Mobile, which delivers smooth transitions between pages, or do an AJAX request and load it into f.ex. body tag.

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: page2.html,
           success: function(data)
           {
            $('body').fadeOut(1000, function(){
            $('body')
                .empty()
                .html(data)
                .fadeIn(1000);
            })
        }
    });
```

If URL is important intercept all link clicks and before changing page make body fadeOut then in every other page make body invisible and fade it in on page load - it should do the trick with the same visual effect.